# Libre desktop replacement for Google Authenticator

Tags: linux, open-source, two-factor-authentication

A handful of webapps I use offer soft-token 2FA, via HOTP and TOTP. Clients that support this include Google Authenticator (proprietary, Android) and FreeOTP (libre, Android / iOS). I am looking for a replacement that is:

- libre licensed
- packaged for Debian (apt, flatpak or snap)
- can run on the GNOME desktop